# Multiplying Textbox Values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm trying to multiply a number from a textbox with other values through a function with parameters. For some reason I keep getting "NaN" as a result.

Here's a watered down version of the code:

```js
function calculate(a, b, c, d) {
  var num1 = a * b;
  var num2 = num1 * a;
  document.write(num1);
  document.write(num2); 
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="apple" min="0" value="0">
<input type="button" onclick="calculate('apple','1.99','2','5')" value="Add to Order">
```

The `document.write` lines are just there for test purposes.  I just don't know why `num1` and `num2` give back "NaN".  Also, I've tried doing `a.value` and `b.value` to no avail.

Comment: If a is apple, then you try to multiply apple with 1.99. How would that become a number. Also all your numbers are strings. Remove the quotes from them. Perhaps you mean `var num1 = document.getElementById(a).value*b` which will multiply the value of your number with the price

Comment: Value you pass for argument is 'apple' which is a string. When u multiply a string with a number you get nothing but a 'NaN'.

Comment: a is apple in your case which is NaN

Comment: as @Oshadha mentioned and because `num1 = NaN` then `num2` will be `NaN` too, because you multiple `num1` which is `NaN` with `apple` which is string and then `num2` will return `NaN` too

Comment: `'apple' * '1.99'` o_O What did you expect this to do?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the String 'apple' which cannot be multiplied.
What you need in this case is getting the value inside the input field:

```
var appleVal = document.getElementById('apple').value;
```

or use 'a' variable instead:

```
var appleVal = document.getElementById(a).value;
```

Tip: Use `parseFloat` function to try to make a number of a string:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Answer (score 0):

`'apple'` is only text, you need to pass:

`document.getElementById('apple').value`.

In your code:

```
onclick = "calculate(document.getElementById('apple').value,'1.99','2','5')"
```

Comment: don't pass strings to represent integer values, change `'1.99'` to `1.99`, etc.

Comment: I don't want to change the original code more than to propose a solution. But I think so is better to pass numbers as numbers. Thanks @Liam.

Comment: or just use `document.getElementById(a).value` in the calculate

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<input type="number" id = "apple" min = "0" value = "0">
<input type="button" onclick = "calculate(1.99,2,5)" value = "Add to Order">

<script>
function calculate(b,c,d){
var a = document.getElementById("apple").value;
var num1 = a*b;
var num2 = num1*a;
document.write(num1);
document.write(num2); 
}
</script>
```

Your mistake is, you are multiplying "apple" string with number.